# how to use find_package in cmake?

Tags: cmake, openssl, libcrypto

when using

`find_package(OpenSSL MODULE REQUIRED)`

I got the following output

`-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so (found version "2.0.0")`

but when i use

`find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED PATHS /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so)`

I am getting an error.

`Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenSSL" with any of the following names: OpenSSLConfig.cmake openssl-config.cmake`

can anyone explain why this is happening and also is it the coorect way of using the find_package in the config mode.

Comment: "can anyone explain why this is happening" - What exactly is **unexpected** by you? Config mode relies on existence of `XXXConfig.cmake` or `xxx-config.cmake` configuration files. This is clearly written in the documentation for [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#full-signature-and-config-mode). If you don't have these files, then you cannot use config mode. `PATHS` option could be used for hing CMake about location of the config file. Obviously, path to the `.so` file cannot help to find `.cmake` file. The documentation describes how `PATHS` is used.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially using 2 different behaviors.

```
# This way is using Basic Signature and Module Mode
# https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html?highlight=find_package#basic-signature-and-module-mode
find_package(OpenSSL MODULE REQUIRED)
```

"
The command has two modes by which it searches for packages: "Module" mode and "Config" mode. The above signature selects Module mode. If no module is found the command falls back to Config mode, described below. This fall back is disabled if the MODULE option is given.

In Module mode, CMake searches for a file called Find.cmake. The file is first searched in the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH, then among the Find Modules provided by the CMake installation. If the file is found, it is read and processed by CMake. It is responsible for finding the package, checking the version, and producing any needed messages. Some find-modules provide limited or no support for versioning; check the module documentation.
"

So essentially in the first one you are using the FindOpenSLL cmake module.
"https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenSSL.html?highlight=openssl"

Where as in the second one you are saying to not use the module CMake has written for you. So of course it is confused as to where to look for.